# Output missing when stderr points to file on multi-threaded stackless python script

Tags: python, pipe, stderr, python-stackless

Consider the following four lines (all identical) which produce the same number of lines from a log file:

```
$ zcat test-catalog.xml.gz | bin/process-catalog.py -b build -T 4 - 2>&1 | wc -l
620
$ zcat test-catalog.xml.gz | bin/process-catalog.py -b build -T 4 - 2>&1 | wc -l
620
$ zcat test-catalog.xml.gz | bin/process-catalog.py -b build -T 4 - 2>&1 | wc -l
620
$ zcat test-catalog.xml.gz | bin/process-catalog.py -b build -T 4 - 2>&1 | wc -l
620
```

Now, consider the exact same lines, except instead of counting the lines from stderr, we count the lines of a file that was read from stderr:

```
$ zcat test-catalog.xml.gz | bin/process-catalog.py -b build -T 4 - 2>test.txt ; wc -l test.txt
612 test.txt
$ zcat test-catalog.xml.gz | bin/process-catalog.py -b build -T 4 - 2>test.txt ; wc -l test.txt
617 test.txt 
$ zcat test-catalog.xml.gz | bin/process-catalog.py -b build -T 4 - 2>test.txt ; wc -l test.txt
619 test.txt
$ zcat test-catalog.xml.gz | bin/process-catalog.py -b build -T 4 - 2>test.txt ; wc -l test.txt
617 test.txt
```

Note that the number of lines vary when I am sending stderr to a file.

The -T option specifies the number of threads the stackless python script is using and when I set it to one thread I get consistent results. So, this seems to be related to something finishing before the last bit of output can be written. Still, I have observed that the script does in fact complete it's task every time (despite not logging it completely).

I am perplexed why the log output would be different depending on where I am sending the stderr. And I am additionally perplexed as to why the number of threads affects this too, despite the script finishing it's task (so it's not ending prematurely).

I would appreciate if anybody could help me make sense of what is taking place here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Switched to log to a file and it now works. Problem is solved. Still a bit curious about why.